# Error in C++ program - "no match for 'operator []' while using vectors

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a simple program that reads a `double` type value from the standard input, prints it on screen and checks whether it's either the lowest or the greatest value of all of the previously loaded values.

My code looks like this:

```
#include "../std_lib_facilities.h"
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    double number;
    vector<double> temps;
    double minimum;
    double maximum;
    while(cin>>number)
    {
        sort(temps.begin(),temps.end());
        temps.push_back(number);
        cout << number;
        if(number>temps[temps.end()])
        {
            maximum=numer;
        }
        else if (liczba<(temps[temps.begin()]))
        {
            minimum=number;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

> no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Vector<double>' and 'std::vector<double>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double> >}')

In lines which contain `if` statements that check if the current `number` is greater or lower than the extreme values of a sorted array of values that so far has been input.

What's the solution for this problem? I assume it's something related to syntax, but I've run out of ideas.

Comment: Please for posterity, **do not** do this: `#include "../std_lib_facilities.h"`; Include the necessary standard library headers, and use the qualified namespace name, aka `std::`

Comment: `temps[temps.end()]` has two bugs. One that you can't access the item at end()  the second is [] requires an index not an iterator.

Comment: Is it `liczba`, `numer`, or `number`?

Comment: @WhiZ That's one of the many problematic features of Stroustrup's introduction book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator[]` takes an *index*, not an iterator.

#### Using iterators

If you want to use iterators (e.g. because you get iterators as part of some algorithm), you can access the first and last elements by dereferencing the iterator:

```
auto first_element  = *(vector.begin());
auto last_element   = *(vector.end() - 1);
auto last_element_2 = *(vector.rbegin());
```

#### Using `operator[]`

The array access operator takes an index, like this:

```
auto first_element = vector[0];
auto last_element = vector[vector.size() - 1];
```

<sup>You can also use `vector.at(index)` instead of `vector[index]`. This adds extra bounds checking (you will get an exception if your index is out of range), but has a runtime performance cost</sup>

#### Using `vector`'s own functions

`std::vector` already has functions built in to access the first and last elements.

```
auto first_element = vector.front();
auto last_element  = vector.back();
```

Answer (score 2):

`temps.end()` is an iterator, not an index.  `std::vector::operator[]` expects an index and since you gave it an iterator it causes the compiler error.  If you want to get the first and last elements in the vector then you can use the `front` and `back` member functions that return the first and last element respectively.  That looks like

```
if(number>temps.back())
{
    maximum=numer;
}
else if (liczba<temps.front())
{
    minimum=number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `operator[]` for vectors takes numerical indexes, **not** iterators. `begin()` and `end()` for vectors return iterators. In your `if` statements, you're passing iterators to the subscript operator instead of numbers, causing the error.

If you want the first and last elements of the vector, use `front()` and `back()`, or dereference the iterators.

```
if(number > temps.back())
{
    maximum=numer;
}
else if (liczba < temps.front())
{
    minimum=number;
}

///OR.........

if(number > *(temps.end() - 1))//Remember that end() is one-past-the-end iterator
{
    maximum=numer;
}
else if (liczba < *temps.begin())
{
    minimum=number;
}
```